# Insert a Page break after specified number of groups

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-3.0

I am creating a report using rdlc files. I want page break  after specified number of group.
ie.break the table rows into Multi columns.
We use matrix.

Please let me know , how to proceed.
Thanks in advance .

Comment: Not sure how easy this will be. I know you can do a page break after *each* group with `PageBreakAfter` but I don't remember seeing a way to specify a certain number of groups...